# How to build a column-based layout of expandable cards (spanning over two columns in <=tablet)? HTML, CSS, jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, flexbox, grid-layout

I'm trying to create a layout as follows:

1. Desktop - no cards expanded:

   [image]
2. Desktop - max one card expanded at a time:

   [image]
3. Tablet and smaller - no cards expanded:

   [image]
4. Tablet and smaller - max one card expanded at a time, spanning over two columns: [image]

I need to do so using HTML, CSS(SCSS) and jQuery.

I have so far tried to use flex, grid and simple css columns declaration. Desktop is not problematic but I'm especially having a tough time figuring out how to span a card over two columns in tablet and smaller devices.

- Flex try in CodePen: https://codepen.io/allgoodtigerwood/pen/eYJLpZq

  ```
  .c-card {
    width: calc(50% - 65px);
    height: fit-content;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 0 0 15px 15px;
    @media (min-width: 1024px) {
      width: calc(33.3% - 65px);
      &:nth-of-type(3) {
        margin-top: 100px;
      }
    }
    &:nth-of-type(2) {
      margin-top: 50px;
    }
    &:nth-child(3n+1) { 
      order: 1; 
    }
    &:nth-child(3n+2) { 
      order: 2;
    }
    &:nth-child(3n)   { 
      order: 3;
      @media (max-width: 1023px) {
        &:nth-child(odd) {
          order: 1; 
        }
        &:nth-child(even) {
          order: 2;
        }
      }
    }
    &--expanded {
      @media (max-width: 1023px) {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
    &__container {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      flex-flow: column-wrap;
      height: 1000px;
      margin-left: -7.5px;
      &:before,
      &:after {
        content: "";
        flex-basis: 100%;
        width: 0;
        order: 2;
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- Column try in CodePen: https://codepen.io/allgoodtigerwood/pen/gOPBvWb

  ```
  .c-card {
    width: calc(100% - 65px);
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 0 0 15px 15px;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
    &--expanded {
      @media (max-width: 1023px) {
        column-span: all;
      }
    }
    &__container {
      @media (max-width: 1023px) {
        columns: 2;
      }
      columns: 3;
    }
  }
  ```

Does anyone have any ideas which could direct me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why a downvote? Please elaborate and hence help me learn to do better next time.

Comment: Yeah I am curious about the downvote too looks like a decent question?

Comment: I couldn't get the full width opened state to work on smaller devices but I did add the staircase layout.

https://jsfiddle.net/98wevz0a/

I removed the 100% width on smaller devices so it works but it is not 100% what you wanted

Comment: Thank you, @NicoShultz! I updated my CodePen flexbox tinker accordingly.